# Any framework specific plugin available in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

Similar to language plugins, is there any plugin available for frameworks(Struts, Spring, Hibernate) in SonarQube?

Thanks,
Laxmi

Answer (score 0):

No, No Framework specific plugin is available in SonarQube.

SonarQube only have plugins for Language and plugins for generating various reports.